# Iterate the number of rows returned from a select statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have a select statement that returns a single column of results that are not "linear" (they are calculated using sum() and group by). I would like to add an additional column to this query that displays their respective count as they appear in the result list.

For example:

## Original Result

```
Sums
----
450
320
117
583
```

## Desired Result

```
Count | Sums
-----   ----
1     |  450
2     |  320
3     |  117
4     |  583
```

Is this possible in MySQL without using a temporary table?

Or more simply, is it possible to just start counting from 1 to n in a select statement?

something like:

```
SELECT ITERATE(1-99)

Iterate
-------
1
2
3
.
.
.
99
```

Perhaps using a stored procedure that accomplishes this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is:

```sql
SELECT
  @`rownum` := @`rownum` + 1 `Count`,
  `t`.`id`,
  SUM(`t`.`qty`) `Sums`
FROM
  (SELECT @`rownum` := 0) der, `table` `t`
GROUP BY
  `t`.`id`;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70fb0/2)</kbd>